# How to catch integers in dictionary keys, most of them string, but some is integers that I need to remove

Tags: python, dictionary, isinstance

How to catch integers in dictionary keys, most of them string, but some is integers that i need to remove.

I tried this:

```
def print_words(filename):
    dict = create_dict(filename)
    for key, val in sorted(dict.items()):

        # Integer filter here! 
        # if not isinstance(dict.key, int)     Something wrong here!

        print '{1:^5}\t{0:<}'.format(key.encode('utf-8'), val)
    return
```

Comment: `if not isinstance(key, int)`

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(k, int)}`

Comment: if not isinstance(key, int)    # thanks, but integers still pass...  maybe it's not an integer?!

Comment: Use `isinstance(k, str)` if you only want strings

Comment: it is give nothing. My key is words, value of key is just counter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `key` and `val` in your loop, `dict.key` is wrong.

You can use this instead:

```
{k:v for k, v in d.items() if not isinstance(k, int)}
```

Or, just replace the line that doesn't work for you with:

```
if not isinstance(key, int):
    # key is not integer
```

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in d.iteritems() if NOT isinstance(k, int)}`

Comment: I still have numbers instead words, from left its value, from the right it's key. here below an example.
  1   84-85
  5   9
 35   a
  1   adder
  1   addition
  5   adventures